# How to install a compiled by Gradle jar into the local Gradle Repository files-2.1 instead of the Maven repository?

Tags: java, gradle, jar

In my build.gradle, I added the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Then using `gradle install` I can copy the resulted jar into the maven repository : `~/.m2/repository`

However, my Gradle repository resides in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`. How can I install the jar into this repository?

Comment: why does it matter to you where it gets installed? Gradle will use the maven repo

Comment: Why do you want want to do this? The Gradle dependency cache is not the same as a Maven repository. This question suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In my case my artifactory repo is down and other engineers are looking into it. In the meantime I want to build my app by getting dependencies from a local cache.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What worked for me is `gradle install -Dmaven.repo.local=the/path/of/the/folder`.

I don't know which IDE you are using but in eclipse you can add a new Run Configuration, in Gradle taks add `install` and in program arguments `-Dmaven.repo.local=the/path/of/the/folder`.

Answer (score 10):

If you insist on manipulating the cache, then your best bet is to write a shell script that will manually replace latest JAR in the cache.

The reason is that Gradle does not come with this functionality built-in, as Gradle uses notion of "local cache" in a strict sense, as opposed to "local repository" which is used by Maven.

The difference is that you are never supposed to save files to local cache manually.

To solve your problem the recommended way: Suppose that project A is a dependency of project B. Then you can call `publishToMavenLocal` command in project A to refresh the depedency. Add `mavenLocal()` repository in `gradle.build` of project B, so every time you build project B, Gradle will check the local repository when resolving the dependency A.

Comment: For Gradle newbies like myself coming from Maven, the 2nd and 3rd lines of this post are important.

Comment: A common use for local development, you add the jar to local repo and once done with testing, you push your code to develop and get a snapshot jar released in artifactory. Mind that the the jar released in artifactory contains the same snapshot version as when working locally. Now you want to get the uploaded snapshot jar in your local and not the one present in your maven local. Would that ever work?

Comment: This is ridiculous: being able to install a jar is a key feature in multistage CI builds. I wish gradle would stop relying on maven (repos) and become feature rich in itself.

Answer (score 2):

mavenLocal() is resolved like this:

In order to make use of a non-standard local maven repository, you can use the following configuration in your build.gradle:

repositories {
    maven {
        url '/Users/manuelj/apache/maven/repository'
    }
}

Comment: did not help, please note that my goal is not using not-standard repository, my goal is publishing

Comment: I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A build.gradle sample to create a Jar file along with its logback dependencies. using mavenlocale()

```
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

target Compatibility = 1.7

//create a single Jar with all dependencies

 task fatJar(type: Jar) {

     manifest {

        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',

            'Implementation-Version': version,

            'Main-Class': 'com.mkyong.DateUtils'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'

    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : 
zipTree(it)

 } 

}
    with jar
}

//Get dependencies from Maven central repository

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
}

//Project dependencies

dependencies {

    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2'

}
```

Reference  [create a Jar file along with its logback dependencies.](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/)

Comment: Where the resulting jar will be installed?