# Kotlin - Import Jar and Use Class

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, jar, package

I have created a library in kotlin using `gradle init` and following the prompts. It compiles and produces a jar file in lib/build/libs. I then have another project that needs to access functions in the library. through intelliJ, I add the dependency by going to Project Settings > Modules > Dependencies and adding the jar file. I then attempt to import the package defined in the library with `import DemoLib` where DemoLib is the name of the package (and the name of the library). This does not compile as it does not recognize the package name. I have also tried importing as a library rather than a jar, with the same results. How can I achieve the desired result?

EDIT: In case it helps here is the code:

Library:

```
package DemoLib

class Library {
    fun someLibraryMethod(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
package DemoClientAppOne

import DemoLib.*



class App {
    val greeting: String
        get() {
            return "Hello World!"
        }
}

fun main() {
    println(App().greeting)
}
```

Not terribly interesting, but the point is that DemoLib is an unresolved reference even after adding the jar as a dependency

Answer (score 1):

You have three options

1. Combine two projects under same IDE project and use Gradle dependencies on project:

`settings.gradle`:

```
include 'project-lib'
```

`build.gradle`:

```
implementation project(':project-lib')
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies

2. Install the library into local repository and add it as a Gradle dependency:

   apply plugin: 'maven'

then run `gradle publishToMavenLocal`

and add `mavenLocal()` repository in `gradle.build` file.

See [How to install a compiled by Gradle jar into the local Gradle Repository files-2.1 instead of the Maven repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47685487/2000323)

3. Use this jar as a flat library Gradle dependency (assuming this jar is located in the `libs` directory:

   repositories {
   flatDir {
   dirs 'libs'
   }
   }

   dependencies {
   implementation name: 'lib-jar-name'
   }

Answer (score 0):

If `DemoLib` is a package,

you need to

```
import DemoLib.*
```

to import all its names into scope. Just `import DemoLib` wouldn't do anything. Or better,

```
import DemoLib.SomeClass
```

to import only one specific name. Actually, if you start typing `SomeClass` (assuming that's a name in your `DemoLib` package), IDEA should suggest adding the import.

Also, it's better to follow [naming conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) from the beginning, and `DemoLib` is not a good package name:

> Names of packages are always lower case and do not use underscores (`org.example.project`). Using multi-word names is generally discouraged, but if you do need to use multiple words, you can either simply concatenate them together or use camel case (`org.example.myProject`).

Comment: point taken about the naming convention, but even if I do `import DemoLib.*`, I get a compiler error.